# Accessing values of an array in a object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is my object :

```
const action = {
durations: ["29 minutes", "34 minutes", "2 heures 48 minutes"],
filteredCollabs: [{…}, {…}, {…}]
}
```

And I would like to access the values of the property "durations".

action.durations[anyIndex] returns "undefined".

That's my whole action creator (redux) :

```
export const searchPeople = (clientAdress, skill, collaborators) => {
  const filteredCollabs = collaborators.filter(collab => collab.skills.includes(skill));

  let collab;
  let origin = "";
  let mode = "";
  let durations = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < filteredCollabs.length; i++) {
    collab = filteredCollabs[i];
    origin = `${filteredCollabs[i].latitude},${filteredCollabs[i].longitude}`;
    mode = `${filteredCollabs[i].mode}`;
    axios
  .get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=${origin}&destinations=${clientAdress}&region=FR&mode=${mode}&key=${config.gmap.key}`)
      .then(response => durations.push(response.data.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
    console.log("durations dans actions : ", durations);


  return {
    type: "SEARCH_PEOPLE",
    durations,
    filteredCollabs,
  }
```

This is what my console.log returns in my browser :

```
durations dans actions : []
0:"29 minutes"
1:"34 minutes"
2:"2 heures 48 minutes"
length:3
__proto__:Array(0)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If there are no syntax / console errors, it should work.

Comment: Probably because `anyIndex` is not 0, 1, 2 ? And you are missing a comma to seperate the properties.

Comment: What is `anyIndex`? Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser.

Comment: The missing comma suggests that you don’t actually have this fixed object. Is it an AJAX response? If so, show how you’re fetching the data.

Comment: anyIndex is 0, 1, 2.
I forgot the comma here, but it is present in my code.

It's an action passed to my reducer in redux.
No error in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an asynchronous problem. 
In fact my array was empty when passed to my reducer since the response from the request was not fast enough. 
In my browser, however, I could see the freshly updated object. Chrome alerted me with the little info icon "value below was evaluated just now".

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Glad you came right! Well done and thanks for informing us.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the comma after durations object

```
const action = {
    durations: ["29 minutes", "34 minutes", "2 heures 48 minutes"],
    filteredPeople: []
    }
```

get your index result

```
consol.log(action.durations[0])
```

Comment: Oops, I edited it (just forgot here because I typed manually). But it's still not working and returns undefined.

Comment: It that case you should do just durations[index] becoz you use  .then(response => durations.push(response.data.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text)); In this case durations is the new array you just created action is not used there Mark as answer if the answer is correct